# Force rJava to use a specific JVM in R

Tags: java, r, rstudio, osx-yosemite, rjava

I want to use [rJava](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rJava/index.html) package in R on MAC OSX (10.10.3). Configuration of the system is as:

```
Haroons-MacBook:~ haroonr$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Haroons-MacBook:~ haroonr$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server
Haroons-MacBook:~ haroonr$ R CMD javareconf
Java interpreter : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java
Java version     : 1.7.0_75
Java home path   : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Java compiler    : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/../bin/javac
Java headers gen.: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/../bin/javah
Java archive tool: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/../bin/jar
Non-system Java on OS X

trying to compile and link a JNI program 
detected JNI cpp flags    : -I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include -I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include/darwin
detected JNI linker flags : -L$(JAVA_HOME)/lib/server -ljvm
clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/../include -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/../include/darwin -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c conftest.c -o conftest.o
clang -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o conftest.so conftest.o -L/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server -ljvm -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/javareconf: line 364: cd: /Volumes/Macintosh: No such file or directory


JAVA_HOME        : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Java library path: $(JAVA_HOME)/lib/server
JNI cpp flags    : -I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include -I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include/darwin
JNI linker flags : -L$(JAVA_HOME)/lib/server -ljvm
Updating Java configuration in /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources
Done.

Haroons-MacBook:~ haroonr$ R --version
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14) -- "Fire Safety"
Copyright (C) 2015 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
```

Now whenever I run in rStudio:

```
.jinit()
   .jcall("java/lang/System", "S", "getProperty", "java.runtime.version")
    [1] "1.6.0_65-b14-468-11M4833"
```

This means that rJava is using Java 1.6, but I don' want to use 1.6.  Java 1.6 creates problems in the further steps. How can I ensure that rJava use only 1.7?

rJava package installed is 0.9-7

Note: Almost similar question is at the [link](https://github.com/s-u/rJava/issues/37), but I am completely lost with otools. Another un-answered similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28133360/rjava-is-not-picking-up-the-correct-java-version)

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion made for the second link?

Comment: I don't know how should I use it with .jinit(). I tried to follow jinit documentation, but was unable to get it properly.

Comment: Yes, I have shown the output above

Comment: Did you reinstall `rJava` after `R CMD javareconf`?

Comment: No, I will do it now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91443/discussion-between-haroon-rashid-and-pascal).

Comment: I re-installed rJava, but still it is behaving in the previous manner, i.e, using java 1.6 and R CMD javareconf is similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latest version (0.9-8) of rJava has fixed this.
I installed latest version from [site](http://www.rforge.net/rJava/git.html) using command

```
install.packages("rJava", "http://rforge.net/", type="source")
```

Now the output by calling jvm is as:

```
library(rJava)
.jinit()
.jcall("java/lang/System", "S", "getProperty", "java.runtime.version")
# [1] "1.7.0_75-b13"
```